# Publish AZWebapp is not working for Linux function app

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-powershell, azure-functions-docker

Publish-AzWebApp is not working for Linux function app

```
Publish-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName Default-Web-WestUS -Name MyApp -ArchivePath C:\\project\\app.zip
```

I am using the above command in powershell and running that powershell in CICD process. But that is not deploying the files to function app(App service deployed) which is in Linux.

Getting the following error:

> Service unavailable

It is working fine for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The following reasons will result in a service unavailable error:

- The function host is down/restarting.
- Platform issue as a result of the backend server not being available/allocated
- A memory leak in the code caused the backend server to return a service unavailable error.

The "Diagnose and solve problems" blade in the Function app should be used to select the "Function app down or reporting" detector.
The diagnostic information regarding the function app and its infrastructure will be displayed by this detector. This will provide some insight into the issues regarding function hosts. Also, look under the Web app restarted section to determine if any platform-related issues contributed to the service unavailable error.
As you are running on Linux platform, then you would get information about the container recycles in the Web app restarted detector.

Comment: Hey @AadityaP ! had it solved your problem else you can share more details so I can troubleshoot?